# splitting a line according to the field separator as a string

Tags: unix, awk, solaris

I have a file as below:

```
10temp3
20/temp4
28 temp 5
```

I am using the below command for splitting the lines and get the last number in the line.

```
awk -F"temp" '{print $NF}' temp3
```

the ouput i got is :

```
> awk -F"temp" '{print $NF}' temp3
10temp3
20/temp4
28 temp 5
```

Surprisingly if i use nawk i am getting the expected output.

```
> nawk -F"temp" '{print $NF}' temp3
3
4
 5
>
```

May i know the reason why?
Is awk not supporting the string mentioned as a separator?

Comment: If the last number in the line is all that you want `sed 's/.*temp *//' file` might be a better choice.

Comment: I want to explore the behaviour of awk here..i know that this can be done by using other tools like sed and perl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed Solaris `awk` only considers a single character. I'd say it's probably due to tradition, and exactly the reason why `nawk` is shipped, as well.

The `-F` switch is really special: it's taking the first character of your quoted string, and discarding the rest, so the `t` remains --- which stands for "look for *tab* as field separator".

Comment: Then if thats the case why it is not considering atleast t as the field separator and printing emp3 as the $NF for the first line?

Comment: @ShiDoiSi: `$NF` signifies the contents of the last field on the line. You are correct that AWK doesn't use dollar signs for variables, it uses them for field numbers. `NF` is the variable that contains the number of the last field.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Right, I didn't pay close attention to his intended output, I thought he wanted to print the number of fields.